# error class 'django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist

Tags: django, django-models

I'm getting the following error message which is not very helpful and there is no other error just this line...

```
**(<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist'>)**
```

This is the code (its an ajax call)

```
@login_required
@csrf_exempt
def smartpage_create_ajax(request):
    if request.POST:

        try:
                json_dict = json.loads(request.POST['site'])

                page = Content()
                page.name = json_dict['name']
                page.user(request.user)
                page.json = request.POST['site']

                page.save()


                return HttpResponse('ok')

        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponse('%s (%s)' % (e.message, type(e)))
```

Could someone tell me what this means as it was working before.

Thank you.

UPDATE:

```
class Content(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to="/logos", blank=True)
    json = models.TextField()

    objects = ContentManager()

    #FK
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="contentpages", blank=True)
```

js

```
  $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: '../content/createpage',
                data: "site="+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(site)),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(ret)
                {
                    // console.dir(ret);
                    if(ret.result)
                    {
                        $('#build-btns').html(ret.html);
                    }
                    else
                    {


                        //report no builds left
                        $('#build-btns').after(ret.html);
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    console.log(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown + 'error');
                    return false;
                },
                complete: function()
                {

                }
            });
        },
```

Comment: Have you run `syncdb` and made sure the `django.contrib.auth` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS`? The error is quite clear - the user table doesn't exists in your DB by the looks of things

Comment: It appears to be the request.user part. maybe because this call is make over ajax that user is 0???

Comment: user table is 100% there and call works when not made over ajax.

Comment: As an aside, if you don't try catching the exception and you have `DEBUG=True`, you will be able to see the entire stack trace in the ajax response (in chrome inspector for example)

Comment: It looks like `request.user` can't find a valid logged in user account  ([it does a DB lookup during the request](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py#L40))

Comment: thats what is so strange DEBUG is true, on anyhting else I see full error details just not the one call. very confused. as a side note, I have removed the user from my models and it works add the user FK back and its gives the same error again. I will update my question with the model.

Comment: @ Timmy O'Mahony I outputed the str(request.user) and it states 'mark' which is me! and this user exists.

Comment: I think there's some code missing here. It shouldn't raise a django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist exception.

Comment: full error now above in update of question

Answer (score 0):

The error means that a get() on the user model did not match any object in your DB
See :https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.DoesNotExist

I would suspect that your currently logged in user does not exist anymore for some reason.  Maybe try to log in again to check if it helps.

Comment: put it does, I dumped out the request.user in the ajax post and it showed 'mark' that user exists.

Comment: @MarkO there's something missing, it cant just output that 1 line of error.

Comment: When I take off my try it states DoesNotExist at /content/createpage
No exception supplied. I 100% have debug = true I get full error messages on all other views same app! so strange. the user I states 'mark' should it be an ID?

Answer (score 0):

Right I don't fully understand why or if this is even an error with Django 1.5. This error went away when I changed the model from...

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

to

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
```

No even when I was inserting a user and have the first code it still give that error. No idea why.